# Rails: ActiveModel join on class.name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create an unusual association where I have a has_one association on a model that uses the foreign_key/primary_key as the class name of the model.

Such as:

```
class ProcessAction
  has_one :process_action_type, :foreign_key => 'class_name', :primary_key => :class_name

  def class_name
    @class_name = class.name #i.e. "ProcessAction::SubclassOne"
  end
end

class ProcessActionType
end
```

The ProcessAction model is a parent model for a series of subclasses that use STI. The ProcessActionType model is a class that lists all the subclasses of ProcessAction, along with other pertinent information that is used in the application, such as processing order, for example:

```
Process Action Types
ID  class_name                    priority visible_to
1   ProcessAction::SubclassOne    1        customer
2   ProcessAction::SubclassTwo    2        admin
3   ProcessAction::SubclassThree  3        both
```

I know I can specify the correct :foreign_key and specify a :primary_key, but is it possible to use the class_name (i.e. "ProcessAction::SubclassOne") as the primary key?

I may have to fall back and simply put a process_action_type_id on each process_action record, but I'd like to avoid that if possible, since it's implicit in the class type of the process_action.

Using Rails 4.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use `has_one` or `belongs_to` as those methods inherently compare the target record's id.

You'd be better making a method to pull the type record when needed.

```
def process_action_type
  ProcessActionType.find_by(class_name: self.class)
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that's one possible back-up solution. I had wanted to avoid a method like this because I also wanted to eager load the type and filter by some conditions. For example: I might filter a customer-facing view by visible_to: customer.

Comment: But a process action has only one process action type so additional filtering from the process action doesn't make sense.  You can add filters to the ProcessActionType model  like `scope :visible_to_customer -> {where(visible_to: ['customer', 'both']}` but it doesn't make sense to try to access this from the `ProcessAction` child classes.

Comment: Also you could do eager loading (albeit manually) by specifying an explicit join in SQL.